# Sublime toggle comment on windows 7

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I can't use the key binding to toggle comment on sublime text 3.

I tried resetting my settings and it didn't work. I noticed that somehow sublime is mapping the "/" to the ";" key, if I press ctrl+; it works. Changing the shortcut to something else works but I don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text's command bindings get a little wonky, since they're keyed to a US keyboard layout (which has the / key where the ; key is on your [I'm guessing] Brazilian layout). Try switching over to a US layout, seeing what character comes out when you press the / key, then binding ctrl-that to the "toggle comment" command.

Comment: You can enter `sublime.log_input(True)` in the ST console to see what character the editor is receiving, rather than changing the key board layout.

Comment: When I press the '/' on the US keyboard layout nothing happens. I typed it on the sublime terminal with the sublime.log_input(True) and nothing happens.